# Cloud config got Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/} from Eureka server

Tags: java, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to implement Discovery First Bootstrap way for my 4 micro-services. First is a config server that takes config from git, and second is an Eureka server. When i'm running docker-compose up my config server is not able to register with eureka. I've got:

*Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/}  Connection refused*

My config server

```
 @EnableConfigServer
    @EnableEurekaClient
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ConfigServerApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
        }
```

application.yml

```
   server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        encrypt.enabled: false
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/Artuwok/artbook-config-repo/
          searchPaths: userservice
          username: Artuwok
          password: Civilization1986
          timeout: 10
          force-pull: true
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      discovery.enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Eureca class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Eureka bootstrap.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

docker-compose.yml with full config

```
version: '3'

services:

  configserver:
    image: configserver:1.0
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - eurekaserver
    restart: on-failure

  eurekaserver:
    image: eurekasvr:1.0
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"


  users_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: users_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=artbook
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - users_db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    depends_on:
      - eurekaserver

  user-service:
    image: userservice:1.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eurekaserver
      - configserver
    restart: on-failure
volumes:
  users_db:
```

So in the end i was able to start-up the services. Pay huge attention to URL on which you are discovering service. **If you are using docker images you must use service name, not localhost in uri and urls's.** My working config

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: false
      discovery.enabled: false
      uri: http://configserver:8888

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You config server and Eureka server both run in Docker. So they can connect with each other using their names in Docker, not `localhost`.

So Eureka service URL should be: `http://eurekaserver:8761/`.

And you should add the code below to your `configserver` configuration in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
links:
    - eurekaserver
```

Comment: I applied settings that you wrote. After that i should be able to see eureka dashboard at http://eurekaserver:8761/ ? In browser a cannot see it. And my config server is not able to register with Eureka.  In fact eureka is available at http://localhost:8761/

Comment: For you, it is available at localhost. But for other docker containers, it should be available with its name.

Comment: Now i got: com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server. For my config server. Don't understand, why config server cannot see the eureka url. My repo https://github.com/Artuwok/artbook

Answer (score 5):

add following in your application,properties file:
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

This makes your eureka server up on default port 8080, also these properties helps you to not register eurekaServer to itself.
 (EurekaServer is itself a client too.)

If you want to run this server on port 8761, add following in your application.properties file:
server.port=8761

PS- It helps when you are not using docker.

Comment: His right, if not using docker, you need to add the server.port to 8761.

Answer (score 1):

I was not using **docker**, but I was getting the same error, I searched a lot throughout the web but didn't find anything.

Then I just stop the server and **updated** my maven dependencies once and then tried to start it service discovery. It worked!!

I hope this will help someone, who is not using and docker and getting the same.

P.S.- Also make sure to have these configurations in **application.properties** or **application.yml**

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=eureka-discovery
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false 
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case devtool is the culprit, please remove the dependency and do maven clean and install. I hope it will resolve the issue provided all the properties mentioned above are in properties or yml file.