# Spring-boot microservice application deployed with docker and kubernetes: Services not communicating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am having issues getting my application services to communicate with each other. What i have is an application that consist of auth-service, discovery-server, api-gateway, merchant-service. I use the eureka server and client dependencies for service discovery. Each of the services is containerized with docker and i use K8 for orchestration.

When i send a request to the server, this is the response i get:

```
2019-05-16 02:48:25.709 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:330) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64aa9553.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$668afe32.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.bizzdeskgroup.paysure.apiservice.ApiServiceApplication.main(ApiServiceApplication.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 86 common frames omitted

2019-05-16 02:48:25.710  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2019-05-16 02:48:25.712 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PAYSURE-API-SERVICE/goteller-api-55bbf4c97f-762gk:paysure-api-service:8082 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:330) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64aa9553.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef85ffa.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$668afe32.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.bizzdeskgroup.paysure.apiservice.ApiServiceApplication.main(ApiServiceApplication.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[paysure-api-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2019-05-16 02:48:25.713  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
2019-05-16 02:48:25.715  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2019-05-16 02:48:25.720  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2019-05-16 02:48:25.734  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1557974905729 with initial instances count: 0
2019-05-16 02:48:25.739  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application PAYSURE-API-SERVICE with eureka with status UP
2019-05-16 02:48:25.741  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1557974905741, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2019-05-16 02:48:25.744  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PAYSURE-API-SERVICE/goteller-api-55bbf4c97f-762gk:paysure-api-service:8082: registering service...
2019-05-16 02:48:25.767  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2019-05-16 02:48:25.788 ERROR 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
```

Here are my Eureka properties and K8 config files:

discovery-server `application.properties` file

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

auth-service `application.properties` file

```
spring.application.name=paysure-auth-service
server.port=8083
```

merchant-service `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=merchant-service
server.port=8087
```

api-gateway `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=goteller-api-service
server.port=8082
```

Comment: please share the eureka properties set and kubernetes resource files to get help

Comment: By looking at the logs ```serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/``` this will not work in docker/kubernetes due to the way containers are deployed and its networking model.

Answer (score 1):

> As per docker networking model, docker containers run in an isolated network namespace.
>
> As per kubernetes networking model, inter service communication can be achieved in various ways:
>
> - Container-to-Container networking
> - Pod-to-Pod networking
> - Pod-to-Service networking

Only in the case of container-to-container networking, microservices/applications can be resolved using localhost.

Assuming in this case, no two containers are running in the same Pod, it is pod to pod networking/ pod-to-service networking.

In this case, make use of kubernetes service discovery feature by setting eureka-server zone aware url to kubernetes service `ex: http://eureka-server:8080`

Here is the sample for your reference:

[k8s-microservices-workshop](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/springboot-microservices-workshop)

[k8s.yaml](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/springboot-microservices-workshop/k8s/k8s.yaml)

```
# config map for eureka clients

apiVersion: v1
data:
  eureka.server.url:  http://eureka-server:9000/eureka
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eureka-server-config-map
---
# config map for zuul proxy

apiVersion: v1
data:
  eureka.client.app1.url: http://${EUREKA_CLIENT_APP1_SERVICE_HOST}:${EUREKA_CLIENT_APP1_SERVICE_PORT}
  eureka.client.app2.url: http://${EUREKA_CLIENT_APP2_SERVICE_HOST}:${EUREKA_CLIENT_APP2_SERVICE_PORT}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: zuul-proxy-config-map
---

# deployment resource for eureka server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eureka-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eureka-server
        image: barathece91/springboot-microservices-workshop-eureka-server:v2.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000

---
# deployment resource for eureka client app1 service
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eureka-client-app1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka-client-app1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka-client-app1
    spec:
      containers:   
      - name: eureka-client-app1
        image: barathece91/springboot-microservices-workshop-eureka-client-app1:v2.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:      
        - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: eureka-server-config-map
                key: eureka.server.url 

---
# deployment resource for zuul proxy

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zuul-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zuul-proxy
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zuul-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zuul-proxy
        image: barathece91/springboot-microservices-workshop-zuul-proxy:v2.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8085    
        env:
        - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-server-config-map
                  key: eureka.server.url
        - name: ZUUL_ROUTES_CLIENT1_URL
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                  name: zuul-proxy-config-map
                  key: eureka.client.app1.url
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: eureka-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka-server
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: eureka-client-app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka-client-app1
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zuul-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    app: zuul-proxy
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8085
    targetPort: 8085
```

**Note**: This is one of the ways of achieving it, Service Registration /Service Discovery is out of the box feature of kubernetes, hence usage of eureka server is optional and it is completely depends on the tech stack and requirement.

Comment: Please verify also other duplicated stack posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336558/cloud-config-got-request-execution-error-endpoint-defaultendpoint-serviceurl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959448/eureka-services-giving-request-execution-error)